# find and then delete the longest occurring sequence of 0 in an array

Tags: c

my array has only 0 n 1 . arr[]={00111000011}
i need to find and delete the longest sequence of 0 and count the remaining elements in the array.

```
int longestsequence(int[] arr, int size)
{
    int longest = 0;
    int length = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1])
        {
            length++;
        }
        else
        {
            length = 1;
        }
    if (length > longest)
    {
        longest = length;
    }
    return longest;

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 0)
            count++;
    }
    if (count > longest)
        longest = count;
}
```

Comment: What's your question/problem? And indent your code properly.

Comment: Can you provide expected output samples?

Comment: Hint: use two separate loops, one to count, one to replace.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly the assignment then the function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below. At least it can be used as a base for your own function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t longestsequence( int *a, size_t n )
{
    int *longest_start = a, *longest_end = a;
    int *start;
    int found = 0;

    int *current = a;
    for ( ; current != a + n; ++current )
    {
        if ( *current == 0 && !found ) 
        {
            found = 1;
            start = current;
        }            
        else if ( *current == 1 && found )
        {
            found = 0;
            if ( longest_end - longest_start < current - start )
            {
                longest_start = start;
                longest_end = current;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( found )
    {
        if ( longest_end - longest_start < current - start )
        {
            longest_start = start;
            longest_end = current;
        }
    }

   if ( longest_start != longest_end )
   {        
        memmove( longest_start, longest_end, ( a + n - longest_end ) * sizeof( *a ) );
   }        

    n -= longest_end - longest_start;

    return n;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int arr[] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, };
    size_t n = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    n = longestsequence( arr, n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: try `int arr[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, };`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY There is a typo in this declaration int *longest_start = a, *longest_end = a;